# Avoid Android Market filtering on optional use of location

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

In my app I try and use location information if it is available. Hence I have those permissions in my manifest:

e.g.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

NOTE: I DO NOT have a  for location, which is the tag I understood was used for filtering in Android Market.

When I upload to Android market I get this reported:

> This apk requests 4 features that will
>   be used for Android Market filtering
>   android.hardware.location.network
>   android.hardware.location
>   android.hardware.location.gps
>   android.hardware.touchscreen

which to me suggests that it will only show up for devices that have location and location.network and gps hardware.

But my use of location is optional and the app will work if it is not avaialble.

Should I remove those permissions from my manifest (will I get exceptions when I try to use it?)?

Is there a way to leave the permissions and avoidAndroid Market filtering based on them?

Comment: I have tried adding an explicit uses-feature, but making them optional thus:       <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />    but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My application has the same problem. I guess this is because the `minSdkVersion` is 4, i.e. Android 1.6. From the [`<uses-feature>` documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#market-feature-filtering):

> In general, if your application is designed to run on Android 1.6 and earlier versions, the android:required attribute is not available in the API and Android Market assumes that any and all  declarations are required.

This makes sense because when you declare a feature as *optional*, you are supposed to use the [`hasSystemFeature()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature%28java.lang.String%29) method from the `PackageManager` to check whether the current device has that particular feature. However, this method itself is available only from API Level 5!

Comment: Good find. Annoying problem. I wish they would have stated more clearly that the `android:required` attribute wasn't introduced until API5 instead of having to dig down into the docs to find that quote. At the top of the page they just say the `<uses-feature>` tag was introduced in API4, but don't mention that the `required` attribute wasn't until API5.