# Make Android "uses-permission" optional

Tags: android, gps, user-permissions

I have these:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />  
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```

And I can check for GPS myself doing this:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

fSupportsGPS = (locationManager.getAllProviders().
    contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));
```

But I still have some doubts. I want my app to run on devices with no wifi/gps/network available. The reason being the only thing I use GPS for is showing user locaion on Google maps. (And that is a minute feature compared to rest of app, so I don't want to have any requirements for it.)

Comment: What doubts do you have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`<uses-feature ...>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#testing) tells Android that the app *must* require the feature and won't work w/o it, so Android doesn't let users install the app (in fact, it won't even show up in the Play Store/Market Place.

To let users who don't have those features install your app, you just have to add the `android:required="false"` option for the appropriate features. That you have already done in the manifest using this XML:

```xml
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

---

To detect if the user has the feature or not (as it is now not compulsory they have it), you can use the Android APIs. This you have already done with this Java code:

```java
locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);   
  fSupportsGPS = (locationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));
```

---

Now, one thing that you cannot do is let users using Android 1.6 and earlier w/o the features install the apps, even if the features are marked as optional. This is b'coz that version of Android doesn't recognize the `android:required` feature as is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6475431/1292652).

---

Another thing to keep in mind is that some `<uses-permission ...>` tags will trigger some implicit requirements for the permission.

To address this issue, quoting from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#testing):

> If you don't want Google Play to filter based on a specific implied
>   feature, you can disable that behavior. To do so, declare the feature
>   explicitly in a  element and include an
>   android:required="false" attribute. For example, to disable filtering
>   derived from the CAMERA permission, you would declare the feature as
>   shown below.

```xml
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

According to [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html), the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />` implies the requirement of a network. To disable that, add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: 1) I was worried the uses-permission perhaps could function as "required" as well. (The app will run fine without those, but just nice if permissions are given.)
2) I was worried using e.g. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission could trigger some further implicit hardware requirements beyond GPS. (For instance, require telephone/carrier/wifi signal)

Comment: Thanks! I now use: "<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />      
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />" because accordingly to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> triggers the "network" requirment.

Comment: What happens if i add the required false to some pemissions and at runtime the doesn't find the hardware? Does it crash?

Answer (score 2):

That `android:required="false"/>` should do the trick. I have a Nexus7, which only has a frontside camera, which is not considered a camera by Android. And with the requirement on a camera it did not show up in the list of supported devices for my app on the play store.

Adding required=false as in

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

made it show up.