# Android ffmpeg needs android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION for compression

Tags: android, ffmpeg, compression, android-permissions, video-compression

I'm using **FFmpegAndroid** library (based on C) on a project in order to compress encode some videos.

The library requires the use of `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission.

If I remove it the compression fails, but I get no additional detail on where the lib requires the permission.

The shell command is:

```
[/data/user/0/app_package/files/ffmpeg, -y, -i, /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VIdidi.mp4, -async, 1, -c:v, libx264, -profile:v, high, -preset, ultrafast, -b:v, 1400k, -maxrate, 1400k, -r, 30, -vf, scale=-1:960, /storage/emulated/0/appname/out.mp4]
```

Do anyone knows on what this is used? As I don't want my users to be asked for a permission without clear understanding on the usage.

Comment: That makes little sense, as `ffmpeg` works just fine on platforms that have no notion of identifying the device's location.

Comment: @CommonsWare actually is a more strange error, it is if i have uses-feature  as a permission. If I remove the permission, or use the permission , it doesn't fail. But placing uses-feature causes an error.

Comment: "i have uses-feature as a permission" -- I have no idea what this means, sorry.

Comment: I mean, i include `<uses-feature /> `instead of `<uses-permission>` in the manifest: `<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:required="false" />`

Comment: you're using android system function. So you need to call for uses-permission not feature. In Nougat all permission is asked when you start the app.

Comment: There is no feature named ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION. That is a nonsense entry.

Comment: Oh, I thought that i could add any permission to the uses-feature in order to make it optional. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430272/make-android-uses-permission-optional i should use "<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" /> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because in the manifest I was using  instead of  on features that couldn't be declared as features, such as ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.