# How to Support Application On Device without Camera Feature

Tags: android, xamarin, permissions, google-play, apk

I have an android application currently on the play store. Although the device runs perfectly well on all devices, I was trying to enable support for some Zebra devices that do not have camera support. Because the application has a camera feature and the device does not, the application shows not supported in the play store.

My question is, is there any way for me to enable the app for use on that device or bypass/not-require the camera permission for that specific device. I did research on this but found minimal information. So to sum it up, I am looking for a way to support my application on a device with no camera feature, and only use the camera permission if the device has a camera. Any help would be appreciated!

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.25" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.some.package" android:versionCode="52">
        
            <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="32" />
    <application android:label="CM Mobile NG" android:theme="@style/HideTitleAndActionBar" android:icon="@drawable/icon_app" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your manifest.  There's a camera permission, and a camera feature.  The permission allows you to use a camera.  The feature *requires* the device to have a camera.  Features should only be used if the device has to have that hardware for the app to work at all.  You should not be using the camera feature (in fact most apps shouldn't use any feature).  It should use the camera permission.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I posted the manifest permissions file. I only see required permissions and camera in there. I do not see the camera feature you mentioned. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Show the actual text (copy/paste, not an image) from **AndroidManifest.xml** file. These will be lines like `<uses-permission…>`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15431005/199364