# Disable NFC Compatibility Check in Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, nfc, nfc-p2p

I have developed an Application which deals with NFC.

Currently my [Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.SGID.MainApp) can not be downloaded from play store if user's device doesn't support NFC.

I want it to be downloaded from all devices i.e. it should be compatible with all devices regardless of NFC support.

I have used this line in manifest :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false" />
```

Will this solve my issue??

I am new to NFC, so I'm not getting any idea what should I do to make it work in all devices. I need some guidance from someone who has already have worked on this technology.

Comment: The uses-feature application shows up in Google Play only for devices that have NFC hardware

Comment: i mentioned android:required="false"..won't it have any effect?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that line should solve the issue if your `minSdkVersion` is above 5.

And in the code you can check if the device supports NFC or not.

```
NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

if (nfcAdapter == null) {       
    // This device doesn't support NFC.
}
if (!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    // NFC is Disabled
} else {
    // NFC is enabled
}
```

Comment: No issue at run-time..btw Thanx.. :) just need to check in manifest

Comment: I can't guarantee, because I never used that code. But as per the docs it should work perfect. Check these links: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html and http://stackoverflow.com/a/6475431/1405120